# How can I make private functions inside packages

Tags: packages, contexts

I want to make private functions.for that purpose,I wrote the following code.

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"]
Begin["`Private`"]
function1[x_]:=x
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

I saved the above package and closed my entire `Mathematica` and again reopen `Mathematica` and evaluated that `Package`.

in `Notebook` I am calling the above function.just like in the following way.

```
 Test1`function1[5]
 Test1`Private`function1[5]
```

it returns output like.

```
 function1[5]
 5
```

that means,functions are working fine but the problem was If you evaluate `Package` second time and evaluate `Notebook` code it returns like in the following way.

```
5
5
```

why it's working like that.clearly I mention full contexts

How can I resolve

Fell Free,If you want edit my question.

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

1. After running your Package code the first time `` Test1` `` is added to the `$ContextPath`.
2. When you call `` Test1`function1[5] `` the symbol `function1` is created in the context `` Test1` ``
3. After calling `` BeginPackage["Test1`"] `` and `` Begin["`Private`"] `` the `$ContextPath` is:  `` {"Test1`","System`"} ``
4. When you use `function1` in `function1[x_] := x` it is found in the `$ContextPath` and therefore it parses as `` Test1`function1 ``.

To avoid this, you need to either remove the symbol `` Test1`function1 `` from the context path before defining `function1[x_] := x`, or you need to give the context explicitly.  Either of these should work:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
Begin["`Private`"];
Test1`Private`function1[x_] := x
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Or:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
Remove[function1]
Begin["`Private`"];
function1[x_] := x
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

If you wish to completely reset the contents of `` Test1` `` every time the package is run you might use `` Remove["Test1`*"] ``.

Comment: If I use `Subbu` instead of `Private` in your use-case1 code.still it's working,then what's the use of `Private`.

as for my understanding,`Private functions` are not accessible from another `Packages`.But here If you call any private functions with full contexts in any another package.It's working fine.

That means,we can't write the `Private functions` in`MM`.

Comment: @subbu there is nothing special about `Private` as a context name; it is merely convention.  Also, "private" doesn't mean cannot be read, it just means "should not conflict (collide) with."  Are you trying to keep people from reading a function definition?  You should look at `ReadProtected` and `Locked` (attributes) if that is the case.  Please consider posting a new question describing what *you* want out of a "private" function if not.

Comment: ok.Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist to write code this way I think you should really try to understand what `$ContextPath` and `$Context` do and how `BeginPackage`,`EndPackage`, `Begin` and `End` control these.

As Mr. Wizard has explained the problem you are facing is that within the private part of the package `` Test1` `` is in `$ContextPath`, but not `` Test1`Private` ``. If neither `` Test1`function1 `` nor `` Test1`Private`function1 `` exist, no `function1` can be found in `$ContextPath` and a new symbol is generated using the current value of `$Context` which is `` Test1`Private` ``. After an explicit call to `` Test1`function1 `` that symbol exists. When you load the package code after `` Test1`function1 `` exists, it will be found in `$ContextPath` and will be used for the definition in the private part and no private symbol `` Test`Private`function1 `` will be used or generated.

The following will put the private context which `$Context` points to before everything else in `$ContextPath`, so now the definition will be made to the private symbol even if the public symbol exists. This should solve your problem and doesn't need to make any changes to other symbols, whether they exist or not:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
Begin["`Private`"];
PrependTo[$ContextPath, $Context];
function1[x_] := x;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

You should be aware that such manual manipulations of `$ContextPath` might have unexpected side effects, so it should be used with some care. Considering this, it probably would be a good idea to explain more clearly what you try to achieve, my impression is that you are probably abusing the namespace functionality for something that probably could be achieved better with other means.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
ClearAll[function1];
function1::usage = "test";
Begin["`Private`"];
function1[x_] := x
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Using `` Test1`Private`function1 `` is despising the whole idea of using a package in the first place.

There is more information in [tutorial/SettingUpMathematicaPackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpMathematicaPackages.html) (You can put this in the help browser.)

Comment: Really,I am not understood,what you are writing .
why you are using `ClearAll[function1];
function1::usage = "test";`.I evaluated your code,your code is working quietly opposite to my requirements.

Actually,we are defining the function as a `Private` but your code returns like in the following way

`5
Test1`Private`function1[5]
`

Comment: No, you need to use `Remove[function1];`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen where will I use `Remove[function1];` code.

Comment: @subbu Please see my answer.