# Call Functions From File Without Modifying Context (Sandbox)

Tags: programming, functions, scoping

Let's say I have file named `test.m` containing

```
test[arg1_] := ( Print[arg1];)
```

What is the best technique for calling test like `test["value"]` while preventing test from being added to the `$ContextPath`?

The following almost works except you must know function values ahead of time

```
Block[{$ContextPath,test}, Needs["test`"];test["test"]];
```

My question is: **How do I generalize the call above to work with any number of functions without the user needing to input definitions manually?**

Comment: @Nasser although I agree generally speaking everything should be in package, let's pretend the example of above is about calling functions that exist in a notebook.  Now surely you are not recommending me wrap the notebook functions with Package statements simply to call a notebooks function from another notebook.  At the end of the day I believe such functionality could be useful and to me it really seems like a solution is to implausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Nasser notes in a comment every Symbol has a context.  You should be aware that Symbols are created during parsing.  See:  [Local variables in Module leak into the Global context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/121).

Alright, now that we worked out what you want here is the simplified answer:

We can perform a similar operation to [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BeginPackage.html) with Block:

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {"runPrv`", "System`"}, $Context = "runPrv`"}, . . .]
```

We can combine this with Leonid's method from [Is it possible to use Begin and End inside a Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/595/is-it-possible-to-use-begin-and-end-inside-a-manipulate/598#598) to keep contexts from being fully resolved until we are ready for evaluation inside the `Block`.  (Note that `` Global` `` Symbols are still created, as discussed above, but they will not be defined.)  I believe `` "runPrv`" `` may be left out of `$ContextPath` in our application so long as we don't change the `$Context` from `` "runPrv`" `` within the Block itself.   Finally we have:

```
SetAttributes[runPrivate, HoldAllComplete];

runPrivate[code_] :=
  With[{body = MakeBoxes @ code},
    Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}, $Context = "runPrv`"},
      ToExpression @ body]]
```

Now:

```
runPrivate[
  Get["test.m"];
  a = 5;
  test[a]
]
```

> 5

Global Symbols `a` and `test` remain undefined:

```
?a
?test
```

> Global`a
>
> Global`test

Comment: +1 The 2nd example is great and helps clarify. This relates strongly to the original question.  How would I modify this following code so `a` isn't defined.  `Block[{$ContextPath = {"test\`", "System\`"}, $Context = "test\`"}, a = 1;]`  I see in your response here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/how-can-i-make-private-functions-inside-packages/24350#24350 you only mention 2 approaches for avoiding to define declarations int the `$Context`.  Is there a technique that avoids pre-pending the context test\` and in addition it doesn't require you run `Clear[function1]` first.

Comment: @Liam You are working against the normal evaluation order, and there may be other approaches depending on what you want, such as a Cell with a unique Context, but that specific case may best be handled as Leonid showed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/598/121), e.g.: ``Block[{$ContextPath = {"test`", "System`"}, $Context = "test`", code = MakeBoxes[a = 1]}, 
 ToExpression[code]]``

Comment: @Liam I put this example in the question.  I think perhaps we finally have what you want?

Comment: Yes.  Now this isn't exactly production quality, but I'm going to assume there isn't really a better way to suppress the message like `z::shdw: Symbol z appears in multiple contexts {test\`,Global\`}; definitions in context test\` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>` except with `Quiet[Block[{$ContextPath = {"test\`", "System\`"}, $Context = "test\`", 
   code = MakeBoxes[p = 1]}, ToExpression[code]], General::shdw]` or is there another way?

Comment: @Liam I was busy updating my answer.  Could you please give me an example using the current `runPrivate` code that produces this shadowing when run in a fresh session?

Comment: They example above throws the message in M8 if I don't have `Quiet`.  For example `Block[{$ContextPath = {"test\`", "System\`"}, $Context = "test\`", 
  code = MakeBoxes[p = 1]}, ToExpression[code]]`

Comment: @Liam That's strange, I'm not getting it in version 7.  Does it help to use `With`, e.g.: ``With[{body = MakeBoxes[p = 1]}, 
 Block[{$ContextPath = {"test`", "System`"}, $Context = "test`"}, ToExpression[body]]]`` ?

Comment: No. But if I run the code twice the `$Context` I believe has been defined and I get no message.

Comment: @Liam for reference does it happen if we leave ``"test`"`` out of the `$ContextPath`, e.g.: ``With[{body = MakeBoxes[p = 1]}, 
 Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}, $Context = "test`"}, ToExpression[body]]]``

Comment: Leaving of `test\`` works without any message

Comment: After some testing of the code I believe there should be a `Remove["runPrv\`*"]` at the end.  Otherwise potential variable conflicts can occur. For example `Attributes` defined with `Protected` cause errors.

Comment: @Liam Could you give me an example of that problem?

Comment: The example you have posted illustrates the problem.  Basically run the code in your example then type in `runPriv\`` and try auto completing Ctrl + K.  Any variables defined will bleed into the next time you run the code.

Comment: example http://pastebin.com/1nsB0qad While we are modifying the code, I am going to ask a quick question.  Is there any way to explicitly force something to be written to `Global\`` inside private context maybe someway to define `Global\`` as another context/variable in your code?

Comment: @Liam Ah, I see.  I was assuming you had only *one* private context and you wanted to keep what you had loaded.  For example, you could run `runPrivate[Get["test.m"];]` and then later run `runPrivate[test["thing"]]` and the call would work.  You could modify the code to use a context of your choosing, or as already proposed clear the context when done.  You could also have `runPrivate` create random context when run, which wouldn't help memory use but would prevent collisions and should work even if you `Locked` something within a prior context.  If you need help with any of these let me know.

Comment: What about my second question about `Global\``?  Is there a way to get this to work.  `runPrv [Global\`a=1]` as in a way to force global variables?

Comment: For documentation purposes.  The following code clears attributes and contexts http://pastebin.com/M2b5DUqK after running the function each time.  The following is supposed to use random contexts http://pastebin.com/2ZTpkYeF but I would guess there is better way to achieve similar functionality.  In addition it often gives `Remove::remal : Symbol Removed[RContext] already removed.`

Comment: Again posting for documentation purposes. Ultimately the code here http://pastebin.com/R6JzhBsU uses `InternalInheritedBlock` to prevent users form modifying `System\`*` values

Comment: @Liam Looking at your last comment it seems you're trying not merely run some code in a separate context but create some kind of sandbox area where arbitrary code can be executed safely.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but just to clarify I am not looking for a secure sand boxing environment in the sense that they can't mess with the system.  It's not like I'm planning to run someone else's code.  I didn't say that explicitly, but that has been the evolving intent.  It would probably be a good idea to add that keyword to the question for anyone that might be searching for such a thing.

Comment: @Liam You also might consider a new question specifically describing that situation; I think a parallel kernel or the like might be a workable solution.  This question never got much attention unfortunately.