# Reassign Functions for Graphic Representation

Tags: graphics, warning-messages

How might I construct a function of the form `Rep[defs,code]`, `graphic[code]` and `display[code]` Such that the following outputs can occur?

```
Rep[
 y[a__] := Graphics[{Circle[],
    Inset[
     graphic[a]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center, 
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]}, ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
 Times[a_, b_] := Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Rectangle[{0, 0}],
    Black, Inset[
     display[a*b]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]
    }, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {85., Automatic}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
 , graphic[y[y[a*b]]]
 ]
```

[image]

```
Rep[ 
 Sum[f_, {i_, max_}] :=
  Graphics[{Circle[],
    Inset[
     Sum[f, {i, max}]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center,
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]}, ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0],
 graphic[Sum[x^2 , {x, 10}]]
 ]
```

[image]

[Here is my current attempt](http://pastebin.com/5eTKBiuf) of creating `Rep[funs,code]`.  The biggest problem that I have currently, is that I am trying to define custom functions on top of System attributes(`Times` & `Plus`).  In addition I was originally going to add a namespace `Gr` to the passed in variables but I feel that there is likely a better way.

Questions are welcome around the current implementation or a slightly better/different implementation.

My question:  **How can I construct the functions above such that they satisfy the graphic outputs?**

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/5

Comment: @rm-rf Thank you for the link.  I think it different(correct me if wrong) because my centers around the issue of being unable to re declare System` values.  I attempted to temporary modify System` values with the chat with Mr.Wizard here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29779 But ultimately it seems values like `Times` and `Plus` can't be reassigned it scenarios like this 2*3.  That has lead me to replacing all values to slightly modified forms to get around this issue.

Comment: I guess so... From a quick read, I thought you wanted to generate something like a modified treeform/dependency graph of your function, which is very close to the linked Q, except you wanted to do it with graphics instead of graphs. On a closer look, it seems that's not the case here. I wasn't fully sure either. I'll edit my comment to simply say "related"

Comment: I feel that it has not received enough attention due to the lack of description of what you want to create.

Comment: @Kuba Is it clear now or should I add further information?

Comment: @Liam I'm sorry, I don't see your edit or new information.

Comment: @Kuba I still don't understand what this question is about.  Sometimes code is more descriptive than text but in this case I have no idea what the purpose is.

Comment: I agree with Mr Wizard, this question would benefit from an introductory paragraph explaining the purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, now I understand your "still" and Liam's last question... you were thinking I consider this question clear... I'm really "missunderstood-guy" here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like what you want to do is apply the temporary definitions in `defs` to `code`, then show the output. Here's what I came up with.

```
SetAttributes[Rep, HoldAll];

Rep[defs_, code_] := Module[{symsTrans, downVals},
    symsTrans = Union[Cases[Hold[defs], 
        HoldPattern[SetDelayed][f_[___], _] :> (f -> "changeMe"[f]), {0, \[Infinity]}]];

    downVals = Union[Cases[Hold[defs], HoldPattern[SetDelayed][f_[a___], b_] :> 
        RuleDelayed[HoldPattern["changeMe"[f][a]], b], {0, \[Infinity]}]];

    ReleaseHold[Hold[code] /. symsTrans //. downVals]
]

(* flatten all graphics into one *)
graphic[obj_] := Module[{ops},
    ops = Sequence @@ Flatten[Cases[obj, Graphics[l_, op___] :> {op}, {0, \[Infinity]}]];

    Graphics[{obj}, ops] //. {
        Graphics[{a___, Graphics[l_, ___], b___}, o___] :> Graphics[{a, l, b}, o]}
]

(* not sure what this should be *)
display[expr_] := Text[expr]
```

Here, `symsTrans` will only allow your custom down values to be applied to the expressions only visible through `code`  i.e. since your custom `Sum` contains `Sum`, we'd be in an infinite loop applying this definition.

Here are the outputs:

```
Rep[
 y[a__] := Graphics[{Circle[],
    Inset[
     graphic[a]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center, 
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]}, ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
 Times[a_, b_] := Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Rectangle[{0, 0}],
    Black, Inset[
     display[a*b]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]
    }, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {85., Automatic}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
 , graphic[y[y[a*b]]]
 ]
```

[image]

```
Rep[ 
 Sum[f_, {i_, max_}] :=
  Graphics[{Circle[],
    Inset[
     Sum[f, {i, max}]
     , Scaled[{0.498, 0.5020000000000002}], Center,
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]}, ImagePadding -> 0,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0],
 graphic[Sum[x^2 , {x, 10}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Let me know if this is what you want (It wasn't very clear to me) or if this doesn't work for other examples you may have.

Comment: This is a better example `ReleaseHold[
 Rep[
   Rational[a_Integer, b_Integer] := ToString@a <> "/" <> ToString@b;
   , graphic[2/3]][[1, 1]]
 ]`  it doesn't work with Rational for some reason.  Although I seemed to have figured it out I think.  It converts it to the following `Times[2, Power[3, -1]]`