# Variable scope similar to other languages

Tags: variable-definitions, scoping

Mathematica, unlike many other languages, defines the variables in the global scope unless it is explicitly asked to define a variable in a local scope, *e.g.*, using `Module`, `With`, or `Block`.

My question is how to define a scoping construct which defines the variables locally by default unless otherwise stated. For instance:

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
Scope[{x (* specify global variables here *) },
  x = 2;
  y = 2;
  a = 0;
  (* x and y both equal to 2 and a is 0 here *)
]
(* x equals to 2, y equals to 1, a is undefined here *)
```

How can one define a function `Scope` as demonstrated above?

Comment: May be you can look at  Begin["scope`"] ..... End[] and see if this does what you want.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html

Comment: @Kuba The example does nothing because `Scope` doesn't exist, but that's what the OP would like `Scope` to do. The OP wants such a scoping construct. (It is right; contexts are the closest thing.)

Comment: @Kuba: 'locally' means in the local scope. I updated the question and added a new variable. I hope it is clear now. Actually, I want to define all the variables in the local scope and only share the ones which are specified in the list (the first parameter of `Scope`) with the global scope.

Comment: @Anon It seems no one is sharing my thougths about ambiguity of the question so I'm deleting my comments :)

Comment: This might not be convenient.  Wouldn't you need to specify *all* user-defined functions you might want to call in `Scope`?  In Mathematica there isn't really a difference between functions and variables like in some other languages.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Just like the other languages that I mentioned, if a variable/function is not defined in the local scope, the global version is used. If it is defined both locally and globally, the local version is used.

Answer (score 15):

### Overview

Here's two functions that operate in a manner close to what you want. The first uses a locally defined context to provide the scoping. The second uses `Block`, and is likely closer to what you wish.

---

### Version 1

Here's a single function that does what you want:

```
ClearAll[Scope];
SetAttributes[Scope, HoldAll];

Scope[{globals : (_Symbol | _Set | _SetDelayed) ...}, body_] := 
Internal`InheritedBlock[{$ContextPath},
  (* Put globals into Global` or equivalent *)
  globals;
  Module[{context, localbody = MakeBoxes[body]},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      BeginPackage[SymbolName@context <> "`"],
      ReleaseHold@MakeExpression@localbody,
      EndPackage[]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'll detail more on how it works, later.

Using the example from [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31699/52),

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
Scope[{x = 2},
 Print[$ContextPath];
 y = 2;
 a = 0;
 Names["`*"]
]

{x, y, a}
(* {context$15569`,System`} *)
(* {"a", "y"} *)
(* {2, 1, a} *)
```

Unfortunately, it also produces shadowing messages for both `y` and `a` because they are first created within the global context, and then added to the local one. I have, yet, to work out how to prevent this.

---

### Version 2

This version uses `Block` instead of moving everything to a separate context. To do so, it needs a couple of helper functions:

```
ClearAll[flatHold];
SetAttributes[flatHold, {Flat, HoldAll}];
{a__flatHold} ^:= flatHold[a]
```

which deals with nested `Hold`, and to simplify things later

```
(scope:Block|Module)[flatHold[a__], body_] ^:= scope[{a}, body]
```

which allows us to do this:

```
Block[flatHold[a, b], a = 5; b = 6; {a, b}]
Module[flatHold[a, b], a = 5; b = 6; {a, b}]
(* 
 {5, 6}
 {5, 6}
*)
```

This works because `Block` and `Module` have the attribute `HoldAll`; an attribute of [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAllComplete.html), however, would have prevented up-values from firing.  Also, we need a method for acquiring the symbols we wish to localize:

```
ClearAll[getSymbols];
SetAttributes[getSymbols, HoldAllComplete];
getSymbols[(Set|SetDelayed|TagSet|TagSetDelayed)[a_Symbol,__]] := flatHold[a]
getSymbols[(Set|SetDelayed)[a_,_]] := 
 Cases[Unevaluated@a , 
  r_Symbol /; !MemberQ[Attributes[r], Protected|Locked|ReadProtected]:> flatHold[r], 
  {0, Infinity}, 1, Heads->True]
getSymbols[expr_] :=
 Cases[Unevaluated@expr,
  s:_Set | _SetDelayed |_TagSet | _TagSetDelayed:> getSymbols[s], Infinity]
```

The second form of `getSymbols` is as complicated as it is because of having to deal with `SubValues`, and the fact that `Head@q[r][y] == q[r]`. There is probably a better way, though. Unfortunately, it does not deal with `UpSet` or `UpSetDelayed`, which I leave as an exercise to whoever can come up with something. The third form allows the user to pass in an arbitrary expression.

With those, the new version of `Scope` becomes

```
ClearAll[Scope2];
SetAttributes[Scope2, HoldAll];

Scope2[{globals:(_Symbol | _Set|_SetDelayed)...}, body_]:=
(
 (* Put globals into Global` or equivalent *)
 globals;

 With[{vars = getSymbols[body]//DeleteDuplicates}, Block[vars, body]]
)
```

which for all practical purposes is a one liner.  Which as you can see

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
Scope2[{x = 2},
 q[x_] := x^2;
 r /: q[r] := 5;
 {y = 2, a = 0, q[2], q[r]}
]

{x, y, a, r}
DownValues[q]
UpValues[r]
(* 
 {2, 0, 4, 5}
 {2, 1, a, r}
 {}
 {}
*)
```

`OwnValues`, `DownValues`, and some `UpValues` are localized to the body of `Scope2`.

Comment: I'll definitely be playing with this this evening.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard its flaw is annoying me. To work around it, I think `Block` is a good option, but that requires getting _all_ the symbols that are defined within `body`. I can easily get a list of Symbols that are `Set`, `TagSet`, and their delayed versions, but not `UpSet` or `UpSetDelayed`. A method would be to evaluate those, see what `UpValues` are generated, and clear them, but I'm hoping to find a less hackish method.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard added a new version which deals with the shadow problem. I still don't have a handle on `UpSet` and `UpSetDelayed`, but it works well, otherwise.

Comment: I only have a couple of minutes to skim this, but is there a reason you can't extract *all* non-System-context Symbols?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that would vacuum up to much. Consider: `q[x] = 7` where `x` is global with a value. Siphoning off _all_ non-System symbols would create issues. Of course, I could avoid _any_ symbols on the `$ContextPath`, but then this would under sample the symbols, e.g. if `x` has a global value, it would not be localized. So, I don't see a clear way to do it by more general means. Let me know if you see one.

Comment: What does `^:=`  do?

Comment: I came here to say that this doesn't keep closures. So variables don't live inside functions

Comment: @Rainb it has been years since I looked at this code. Do you have an example involving closures?

Comment: @rcollyer I don't think it's a problem with your code it's a problem with the Function construct that doesn't keep variables even after `/.OwnValues` so it's fine

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is related in concept to [Call Functions From File Without Modifying Context (Sandbox)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29779/121).

As Nasser comments, you may find utility in [`Begin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Begin.html) and [`End`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/End.html) and related [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BeginPackage.html) and [`EndPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EndPackage.html).  You'll have some trouble turning this into a function as normally `Begin` and `End` must be on separate lines from the rest of your code.

- For an explanation of this please see: [Local variables in Module leak into the Global context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/121)
- One way to work around the problem: [Is it possible to use Begin and End inside a Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/595/121)

If it is acceptable to use lines before and after your code rather than a Module-like function you do your own [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ContextPath.html) manipulation.  Here is a start:

```
Module[{isEx, conlst},
 BeginLocal[] := Module[{con},
   conlst = $ContextPath;
   BeginPackage[SymbolName@con <> "`"];
  ];
 System`EndLocal[] :=
   If[ValueQ@conlst, EndPackage[]; $ContextPath = conlst; Clear@conlst];
]
```

Now:

```
x = 1;
y = 1;

BeginLocal[]

Global`x = 2;
y = 2;
a = 0;

EndLocal[]

{x, y, a}
```

> ```
> {2, 1, a}
> ```

Note that I had to reference the global `x` with an explicit context.  I am trying to find a way around that now.  One must deal with the fact that there is (apparently) [no way to expose specific symbols to the context path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728).

Answer (score 2):

The OPs question begins with: "Mathematica, unlike many other languages, defines the variables in the global scope unless it is explicitly asked to define a variable in a local scope, e.g., using Module, With, or Block."

This is not completely correct, and Mathematica has a method of doing local scoping -- it is just different from most other languages. It is possible to specify that all variables *within each notebook* be local to that notebook. This is done with the menu item:

Evaluation -> Notebook's Default Context -> Unique to this Notebook

So for instance, if you open a notebook (or choose a new notebook) and set

```
a = 5
```

then `a` has this value only within the given notebook. Opening another window, the value of `a` is unspecified.

Comment: Additionally, c/c++ did not have a "complete" form of this until very recently. At best, you'd scope to the nearest enclosing function/class/namespace/file (and file was iffy). More recently, `{int a = 5;}` scopes `a` to the enclosing braces. Mma could do this via `Block` and crew, long ago. And, the function parameters have always been scoped, so it is only the local vars that needed extra attention.