# Symbol-handling, force-replace instanced variables within functions!

Tags: symbols, variable

Currently I am stuck with the issue of renaming an instanced variable like `r1$23314` to a global one.

This issue arises as I need to use a "localizeAll" Module in a `Module`/`Block` itself. Here's  [a link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/treat-all-variables-as-local-in-a-module).

In particular I would like to rename this custom-made function's parameters.

```
b5[r1, r2, z] //. {Names["r1$*"][[2]] -> r1}
```

Sadly the output is still:

$ \scriptsize \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1. \text{r1$\$$295581} \\ \normalsize
 \frac{\text{r1$\$$295581} (1. \text{r1$\$$295581}+1. \text{r2$\$$295581})}{1. \text{r1$\$$295581}+2. \text{r2$\$$295581}} \\ \normalsize
 \frac{\text{r1$\$$295581} (1. \text{r1$\$$295581}+1. \text{r2$\$$295581})}{1. \text{r1$\$$295581}+0.946259 \text{r2$\$$295581}} \\
\end{array}
\right)   $

Thank you.

Comment: ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@r1$23123, "$"]?

Comment: that and more in  [Pattern matching multiple symbols names and powers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75294/pattern-matching-multiple-symbols-names-and-powers)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Algohi: How exactly do I use  
ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@r123123,""] ? As for duplicates, symbol handling is not just a pattern-matching  in my case.

Comment: @chrisoutwright use "$" instate of " "

Comment: The whole issue is that I use the same code with minor alteration at the end to define functions,preferably totally localized, so that I can rerun them and get a dump for statistical analysis.  [my file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtnnnbm218q6ys0/fineco_modules.nb?dl=0).
Some of these functions I would like to define again as functions. If I don't localize a codeblock then I can run it only once as my variables will be populated somehow. As to "ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@r123123,"$"]" how do I apply it to my expression?

Comment: ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@Names["r1$*"][[2]], "$*"]
-> $Failed 
what exactly is wrong? Sorry the pattern-matching page won't help me at all as it doesn't handle replacement within functions and be functions still!!

Comment: The whole problem is stated here again [link] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81068/replace-instanced-variables-within-module-return-functions-for-dynamic-tooltip) .
Maybe now a solution can be found