# Replace instanced variables within module-return functions for dynamic Tooltip

Tags: replacement

Currently I am stuck with the issue of renaming an instanced variable like `r1$38655` to a global one. The function is created within a  "localizeAll" Module. Here's a link to  [localizeAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/treat-all-variables-as-local-in-a-module).

In particular I would like to rename the custom-made function's parameters at the end of the code:

```
   ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"]; CloseKernels[];

   ClearAll[localizeAll];
   SetAttributes[localizeAll, HoldAll];
   localizeAll[code_] := With[{vars = 
   Join @@ Union@
   Cases[Hold[code], 
   s_Symbol /; 
     Context[s] == "Global`" && Length@OwnValues[s] == 0 && 
      Length@DownValues[s] == 0 :> Hold[s], Infinity, 
   Heads -> True]},(*Module[{##},code]&@@vars*)(*original*)
   vars /. Hold[v___] :> 
   Module[{v}, code] (*Leonid Shifrin's suggestion*)]

   (*now my actual function*)

    conscalc[d1_, d2_] := 
    localizeAll[
     Block[{h1 = d1, h2 = d2, y, c, q, tt, em, tm, all, ll, i, j, allmat, NBN},


  CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[8]; Kernels[]; n := 2; m := 2

; cons := Table[Subscript[(y), (i - 1)], {i, n + 1}]
; consN := Table[Subscript[(cons), j], {j, m}]
; fconsN := Table[Subscript[c, i - 1, j], {i, n + 1}, {j, m}]
; prices := Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, n}]
; endows := Table[Subscript[e, i - 1], {i, n + 1}]
; endowsN := Table[Subscript[(endows), j], {j, m}]
; qprices := Table[Subscript[q, i], {i, n}]

; probsN := Table[Subscript[(probs), j], {j, m}]

; thetaNN := Table[Subscript[(tt), i, j], {i, n} , {j, m}]

; thetaN := Table[Subscript[(theta), j], {j, m}]
; sallaN := Table[Subscript[(salla), j], {j, m}]
; endows := Table[Subscript[e, i - 1], {i, n + 1}]
; endowsN := Table[Subscript[(endows), j], {j, m}]
; solv := Table[Subscript[(sol), i], {i, n + 2}]
; solvN := Table[Subscript[(solv), j], {j, m}]
; mat := Table[Subscript[(mm), i, j], {i, n + 1}, {j, n + 1}]
; matN := Table[Subscript[(mat), z], {z, m}]
; parmat := mat[[1 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]]
; parmatN := Table[Subscript[(parmat), z], {z, m}]
; lagraN := Table[Subscript[(ll), z], {z, m}]

; allmat := Table[Subscript[(em), i, j], {i, n + 1}, {j, n + 1}]
; allmatN := Table[Subscript[(allmat), z], {z, m}]
; allmat2 := Table[Subscript[(dm), i, j], {i, n + 1}, {j, n + 1}]
; allmat2N := Table[Subscript[(albmat3), z], {z, m}]
; allmat4 := Table[Subscript[(tm), i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]
; allmat4N := Table[Subscript[(allmat4), z], {z, m}]
; comthetaN := Table[Subscript[(all), j], {j, m}]
; fixmat := mat[[1 ;; -1, 1 ;; 1]]
; fixmatN := Table[Subscript[(fixmat), z], {z, m}]
; NBN := Table[Subscript[(NB), j], {j, m}]

; pay := Table[(Subscript[a, i, j]), {i, n}, {j, n}]

; baby := Table[Subscript[g, i], {i, n}]
; babyN := Table[Subscript[(baby), z], {z, m}]
; baby2 := Table[Subscript[o, i], {i, n}]
; baby2N := Table[Subscript[(baby2), z], {z, m}]





; LAGRANGE[f0_, g0_] := 
 Module[{f = f0, g = g0}, 
  l = Table[Subscript[y, i - 1], {i, 0, n + 1}]; 
  Gradf = Table[D[f, l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[l]}]; 
  Gradg = Table[D[g, l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[l]}];
  Solve[{Gradf == \[Lambda] Gradg, g == 0}, Append[l, \[Lambda]]]]

; SASSIGN[f0_, g0_, n0_, b0_] := 
 Module[{f = f0, g = g0, n = n0, b = b0}, 
  f := Table[Subscript[(w), z], {z, n}]; 
  Do[Subscript[(w), j] = g[[All, j, 2]], {j, 1, n}]; 
  f = Transpose[f]]


; Vf[j_, \[Alpha]_] := Log[cons[[j]]]

; probsN = h2
; pay = {{1, 1}, {1, 3}}

;(*endowsN=Table[{Sequence@@Table[ent[[j,i]],{i,1,3}]},{j,2}]*);
; endowsN = h1;
;  \[Alpha] = {(1/Subscript[v, 1]), (1/Subscript[v, 2]), (1/100), (1/
   200), (1/100)};
; \[Beta] = {(Subscript[x, 1]), (Subscript[x, 
   2]), (0.3), (0.5), (0.5)}

; i = 1; While[i <= n, Subscript[g, i] = {pay[[i]].prices}; i++] 

; parmat = {(-1)*qprices}
; allmatt4 = baby

; i = 1; While[i <= n, parmat = Append[parmat, pay[[i]]] ; i++]  

; i = 1
; j = 1

; Do[fixmatN = (ReplacePart[
   fixmatN, {j, 1, 
     i} -> {-consN[[j, 1, i]] + endowsN[[j, i]]}]), {j, m}, {i, 
 n + 1}]
; allmat = ArrayFlatten[{{parmat, fixmat}}] 

; i = 1; 
; While[i <= m, 
allmatN = (ReplacePart[allmatN, 
   i -> (ArrayFlatten[{{parmat, fixmatN[[i, 1]]}}])]) ; i++]
; allmat2N = allmatN[[1 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]]

; i = 1
; j = 1

; Do[Subscript[(allmat4), z] = RowReduce[allmat2N[[z]]], {z, m}]
; Do[(Subscript[(tt), i, j]) = allmat4N[[j, i, 3]], {i, n}, {j, m}] 

; thetaNNN = Transpose[thetaNN]
; Split[thetaNNN, #2 - #1 < 2 &] 

; allmat6N := allmatN[[1 ;; -1, 1 ;; 1]]

; fixmatN[[1, 1, 3]]
; Do[(Subscript[(NB), j]) = -fixmatN[[j, 1, 1]] - 
  thetaNNN[[j]].allmatt4, {j, m}] 



; NBN

; Do[(Subscript[(ll), j]) = 
 Vf[1, \[Alpha][[j]]] + \[Beta][[j]] * 
   Sum[probsN[[j, i - 1]]*Vf[i, \[Alpha][[j]]], {i, 2, 
     n + 1}], {j, 1, m}] 

; \[Lambda] := Subscript[y, -1]
; lagraN

; Do[Subscript[(salla), j] = 
 SASSIGN[sal, LAGRANGE[lagraN[[j]], NBN[[j]]], 4, 2], {j, 1, m}]
; sallaN = Flatten[sallaN, 1]
; sallaN = sallaN[[1 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]]

; i = 1
; j = 1;

; amb = 
Solve[{baby[[1]] == Subscript[q, 1], 
  baby[[2]] == Subscript[q, 2]}, {Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 
  2]}]
; i = 1; While[i <= n, Subscript[o, i] = amb[[All, i, 2]]; i++];
; Do[Subscript[p, i] = Subscript[o, i], {i, 0, 2}]

; Do[Subscript[(cons), j] = sallaN[[j]], {j, m}]
; consN = Flatten[consN, 1]

; i = 1
; j = 1

 ; While[
 j <= m, {{Do[(Subscript[(y), i - 1]) = sallaN[[j, i]], {i, 1, 
    n + 1}]}, {Subscript[all, j] = 
   Simplify[-thetaNNN[[j]]]} , {Do[
   Subscript[c, i - 1, j] = sallaN[[j, i]], {i, 1, n + 1}]} }; j++];

; fconsNt = Transpose[fconsN]
; Simplify[fconsNt]

; equi = {{((Sum[fconsNt[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]) - (Sum[
      endowsN[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]))}, {(Sum[
     endowsN[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}]) - (Sum[
     fconsNt[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}])}};
; eka = {{(Sum[fconsNt[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]) - (Sum[
      endowsN[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]) == 
   0} , {(Sum[endowsN[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}]) - (Sum[
      fconsNt[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}]) == 0}};
; With[{ equk = equi, equila = eka, r1 = Subscript[x, 1] , 
 r2 = Subscript[x, 2] , v3 = (Subscript[v, 1]) , 
 v4 = (Subscript[v, 2])}, 
Manipulate[{{r1}, {r2}, {v3}, {v4}}; {Plot3D[
   equk, {Subscript[q, 2], 0, 5}, {Subscript[q, 1], 0, 5}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
  ContourPlot[
   equila, {Subscript[q, 2], 0, 2}, {Subscript[q, 1], 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic]}, {r1, 0, 3}, {r2, 0, 3}, {v3, 10, 
  500}, {v4, 10, 500}, LocalizeVariables -> False]]

; Subscript[x, 1] = 1
; Subscript[x, 2] = 1
; Subscript[v, 1] = 200
; Subscript[v, 2] = 200

; qsolv = 
Solve[(Sum[fconsNt[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]) == (Sum[
     endowsN[[j, 1]], {j, 1, m}]) && (Sum[
     fconsNt[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}]) == (Sum[
     endowsN[[j, 2]], {j, 1, m}]), {Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 
  2]}, Reals];
; tol = SASSIGN[tol, qsolv, 2, 0]
; Subscript[q, 1] = tol[[1, 1]]
; Subscript[q, 2] = tol[[1, 2]]

; Simplify[comthetaN];
; Simplify[fconsNt]]]



 g = 30; h = 10
 consume := Table[Subscript[(e), j], {j, 1, h}]
 qprix := Table[Subscript[(o), j], {j, 1, h}]
 thet := Table[Subscript[(r), j], {j, 1, h}]

 a[i_, j_, k_] := {{e1, e2, e3}, {e4, e5, e6}}

 po[i_, k_] := {{0.05 + (i/1000), 0.95 - (i/1000)}, {0.1 + (k/1000), 0.9 - (k/1000)}}



 b5[r1_, r2_, z_] = conscalc[{{r1, r1, r1}, {r2, r2, r2}}, po[z, z]]
```

The output is:

$ \small \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \{1. \text{r1$\$$38655}\} & \left\{\frac{\text{r1$\$$38655} (1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+1. \text{r2$\$$38655})}{1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+2. \text{r2$\$$38655}}\right\} & \left\{\frac{\text{r1$\$$38655} (1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+1. \text{r2$\$$38655})}{1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+0.946259 \text{r2$\$$38655}}\right\} \\
 \{1. \text{r2$\$$38655}\} & \left\{\frac{\text{r2$\$$38655} (1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+1. \text{r2$\$$38655})}{0.5 \text{r1$\$$38655}+1. \text{r2$\$$38655}}\right\} & \left\{\frac{(0.946259 \text{r1$\$$38655}+0.946259 \text{r2$\$$38655}) \text{r2$\$$38655}}{1. \text{r1$\$$38655}+0.946259 \text{r2$\$$38655}}\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

My whish would be a replacement of r1$38655 to r1 as well as for r2 for the function. Pattern-matching like:

```
    ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@Names["r1$*"][[2]], "$*"]
```

Don't seem to work

Omitting the localizeAll enables me for a correct specification. But I can't run a similar nonlocalized module (for example giving me instead of consumption values the state prices) to produce a function like the first without localizeAll (variables will be populated then and errors appear). For example this function (same module with alteration without localizeAll Block)

```
     i = 0
     k = 0

     b4[e1_, e2_, e3_, e4_, e5_, e6_, r3_] =  Simplify[runoncepprices[{{e1, e2, e3}, {e4, e5, e6}}, Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 2], po[r3, r3]]]

    ne = Simplify[b4[Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r,2], Subscript[r, 2], Subscript[r, 2], z][[1]]]
    de = Simplify[b4[Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2], Subscript[r, 2], Subscript[r, 2], z][[2]]]

    With[{ne1 = ne, de1 = de, r2 = Subscript[r, 2]}, Manipulate[{{z}, {r2}};
      With[{plot1 = Plot[{{ne1}, {de1}}, {Subscript[r, 1], 0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotLabel -> {{0.05 + (z/1000), 0.95 - (z/1000)}, {0.1 + (z/1000), 0.9 - (z/1000)}}]}, 
       With[{plot2 = plot1}, {Dynamic@Tooltip[plot2, (With[{zay = MousePosition["Graphics"]}, {N[zay]}])]}]], {r2, 0, 1000}, {z, 0, 1000}, LocalizeVariables -> False]]
    ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"]; CloseKernels[];
```

The graphic would then represent state prices p1 and p2 with changes in probabilities and aggregate endowments of the agents. x-axis is aggregate endowment of Agent 1 (r1) in period zero and period 1 with two states. r2 can be manipulated as well as the probabilities (z is a increment changer in the defined probabilities within the vector of function po)
The idea in the end is that I would like to show the first function values in the tooltip of the graphic depending on the mousevalues.

[image: Easy Debreu-Model]

Thanks.

Comment: That's a fairly large example. It would be helpful to have a much smaller one that still shows the underlying issue.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I tried to state the problem with the output of "r$$38655" etc. only, but the solution "  ToExpression@StringDelete[ToString@r$38655, "$*"]" seemed not to be workable in any way. Therefore I stated my whole problem.

Comment: Can anybody help me with replacing the temporary variables in the example above with a concrete code? This would help me enormously.
As last remedy I can always only use one nonlocalizeAll'ed module as function and just append all therein generated functions to a array. Sadly that there's no other way so far for me.

Comment: @Daniel, the underlying issue has been stated here [link] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80751/symbol-handling-force-replace-instanced-variables-within-functions) . But I does not work for me in this context.

Comment: My question is then this: How did those localized variables show up to begin with? So what would be useful is a small but complete example that gives full input and the (undesired form of) output. What you have provided is an incomplete example (at the link) and a complete but rather large example here.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement rules are like these for a variable with name "R1" [Ri].
Also added is a "s12" [sij] unique variable. It is important to set the rule immediately to the expression where a module is called with the localizeAll function build into it:

`[expression-to-replace] /. Flatten[{Table[
    Symbol["R" <> ToString[ToExpression["i"]] <> "$" <> 
       ToString[$ModuleNumber - 1]] -> Subscript[R, i], {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[Symbol[
      "s" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j] <> "$" <> 
       ToString[$ModuleNumber - 1]] -> Subscript[\[Sigma], i, j], {i, 
     1, n}, {j, 1, n}]}]`