# Symbolic manipulations of predefined variables without numerical substitution

Tags: evaluation, syntax, scoping, hold

As a novice in Mathematica I would like to expand an expression without substituting its variables so that

```
x = 4; y = 4;
Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2]
```

generates the same output as

```
x =.; y =.;
Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2]
```

The only option I found was

```
x = 4; y = 4;
Expand[(Hold[x]^2 + Hold[y]^2)/Hold[x]^2]
```

But that is not a feasible solution for more complex expressions. Surely there must be a simpler way to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why fight against your own definitions? There is an infinite supply of more symbols if you need more. You can also adjust the formatting of symbols using `Format`, for example `Format[xx] = "x"` means that `xx` will henceforth print as `x`, though it remains different from the symbol `x`. You can (and should!) localize symbols using `Module`.

Comment: Just for context, I am writing a text containing calculations. To keep things readable I would like to be able to re-use the same symbols, even after defining them

Comment: Why is the solution using `Hold` not feasible? You can always use something like `Unevaulated[...] /. {x->Hold[x], y->Hold[y]}` to replace all symbols before evaluation, or even `Unevaluated[...] /. sym:x|y :> Hold[sym]`

Comment: Have you seen `Module` and `Block`? They are just solving the problem of re-using symbols independently of their values received before.

Comment: It seems to me that the title might be too restrictive. It should maybe be something like "symbolic manipulations of predefined variables without numerical substitution"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Contents:**

- **Purpose of codes below**
- **Method 1: Create a new context**
- **Method 2: Turn the variables to strings**
- **Method 3: Localize all variables and use `Format`**

#### Purpose of codes below

Below are some possibilities that try to avoid using tedious code each time one wants to use symbolic computations with predefined variables. That is, the purpose of the codes below is to avoid having to use multiple functions such as `Hold`, `HoldForm` (like `Hold` without the wrapper), `Block`, `Module` and most importantly **avoiding** the tedious task of **having to specify which variables need to be hidden from their definitions**.

#### Method 1 : Create a new context.

---

**Advantage**: Make multiple symbolic computations in multiple cells while the context is activated.

**Risk**: Forgetting to leave the context or having to make a keyboard shortcut that makes context opening  and context closing cells. Error messages  of shadowing are shown each time. If we use [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) then there is the risk that errors we do not want will not be seen.

**Tedious part**: One has to make 2 other cells with function calls BeginLocal[](defined below) and EndLocal[](defined below) before writing what we want. Also context errors will appear each time. Finally we have to remember to evaluate EndLocal[] once we are done.

---

The answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31699/86543) provides one way to use symbolic calculations with predefined variables. The tedious and maybe dangerous part with that method is that one has to do 3 steps:

- 1: Evaluate the function BeginLocal[] (defined below) in one cell
- 2: The code you wanted to use in another cell
- 3: Evaluate the function EndLocal[] (defined below) in another cell

There is maybe a risk here that the user will forget to use `EndLocal[]`. One should probably make both the `BeginLocal[]` and `EndLocal[]` cells before writing the code for an expression we want to manipulate and then we have to **evaluate EndLocal[] at the end**. Perhaps this could be made easier with keyboard shortcuts. Search stack exchange for methods to create keyboard shortcuts.

The code from that answer:

```
Module[{isEx, conlst}, 
BeginLocal[] := Module[{con}, conlst = $ContextPath;
BeginPackage[SymbolName@con <> "`"];];
System`EndLocal[] := 
If[ValueQ@conlst, EndPackage[]; $ContextPath = conlst; 
Clear@conlst];]
```

**Example**

```
x=4;y=4;
```

First input cell:

```
BeginLocal[]
```

Second input cell :

```
Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2]
```

Third input cell :

```
EndLocal[]
```

#### Method 2: Turn the variables to strings

**Advantage**: No need to use two functions in two different cells and no context shadowing errors.

**Risk**: It seems unlikely for how I use Mathematica but maybe one would defined both the variable x and the string "x" in which case the code below will not work.

**Tedious part**: we have to use the function hide(defined below) like code //hide each time. If we have many symbolic calculations it might be better to use the BeginLocal[] and EndLocal[] functions from the previous method.

The code below is inspired by the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37924):

```
ClearAll[hide];
SetAttributes[hide, HoldAll];
hide[code_] := 
ReleaseHold@
ReplaceAll[Hold[code], 
s_Symbol /; Context[s] == "Global`" :> ToString@Unevaluated@s]

x = 4; y = 4; Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2] // hide
```

Out: $$ \frac{\text{y}^2}{\text{x}^2}+1 $$

However, although the expression looks like what we wanted, x and y are strings as can be checked using `FullForm`:

```
x = 4; y = 4; Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2] // hide // FullForm
```

Out:  `Plus[1,Times[Power["x",-2],Power["y",2]]]`

#### Method 3: Use Format

**Advantage :** No issue with the case where one defines both x and the string "x" as "x" is used only for formatting and same advantage as the previous method.

**Tedious part**: Same as for the previous method

Using `Format` was mentioned by @user293787 in the comments.

The code below is inspired by the answer (same as for method 2) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37924):

```
ClearAll[hide];
SetAttributes[hide, HoldAll];
hide[code_] :=
Module[{vars, modcode},

(*association of the form Hold[variable]->{variable to string, 
localized variable (added dollar sign followed by number)}*)

vars = 
 Association@
  Cases[Hold[code], 
   s_Symbol /; 
     Context[s] == 
      "Global`" :> (Hold@s -> {ToString@Unevaluated@s, 
       Unique@Unevaluated@s}), All];

(* modified input code/expression with localized variables *)

modcode = 
 ReplaceAll[Hold[code], 
  s_Symbol /; Context[s] == "Global`" :> Last@vars@Hold@s];

(*Formating the localized variables to look like the original \
variables*)

Do[With[{string = First@vars@key}, 
  Format[Last@vars@key] := string], {key, Keys@vars}];

modcode // ReleaseHold

]
```

**Example**

```
x = 4; y = 4; Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2] // hide
```

Out: $$\frac{\text{y}^2}{\text{x}^2}+1$$

Answer (score 5):

You need only one [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) if you do it like this

```
x = 4; y = 4;
Block[
   {x, y},
   Hold[ Evaluate @ Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2] ]
]
```

[image]

However, as pointed out by @user293787 in the comments, you are unnecessarily making it difficult to yourself for no apparent reason.

If you want to clear the definitions of $x$ and $y$ you can use [`Unset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) or [`ClearAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html).

I suggest you learn to embrace a different programming style that take advantage of [Functional Programming](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/dev001/), keeping variable definitions to a minimum. Learn about [Scoping Constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html) and [Transformation Rules](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html) like [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and keep a [clean Kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175670/10397).

```
ClearAll[x, y]

expr = Expand[(x^2 + y^2)/x^2]
```

> 1 + y^2/x^2

```
ReplaceAll[expr, {x -> 4, y -> 4}]
```

> 2