# Replace inside a Held expression separate context

Tags: replacement

How do I replace content inside a Held expression without local values coming through?
For example if you run the following code you get `g[2]` instead of `g[x]`(the intended form).

```
x = 2;
Replace[HoldComplete[g["x"]], {
  y_String :> With[{
     eval = Symbol[y]},
    eval /; True]
  }, {0, Infinity}]
```

The following questions are related

- [Constructing a Sandbox](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29779/call-functions-from-file-without-modifying-context-sandbox)
- [Replace inside Held Expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replace-inside-held-expression)

**EDIT:** Although rm-rf's trick is clever it partially works.  His current code adds an additional defer to the current code.

```
InputForm@HoldComplete[g["x"]] /. 
  s_String :> With[{x = ToExpression[s, InputForm, Defer]}, x /; True]
```

returns `HoldComplete[g[Defer[x]]]`  instead of `HoldComplete[g[x]]`.  Ultimately you could strip out the `Defer`s which is likely what I will end up doing.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/7288

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third argument of `ToExpression` with the [Trott–Strzebonski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/) can be used to do this:

```
HoldComplete[g["x"]] /. s_String :> 
    With[{x = ToExpression[s, InputForm, Defer]}, x /; True]
(* HoldComplete[g[x]] *)
```

Comment: `Sequence` might be used to get around this issue but I'm just running off intuition.

Comment: @Liam, if that's a problem why not just strip out the `Defer` with a replacement `/. Defer[x_] :> x`

Comment: I modified your code slightly to the [following](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=z5RJUyAa).  It works quit well.  You are quit right I will stop posting partial questions especially to chat.

Comment: Reference for Trott-Strzebonski : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/45020.

Answer (score 4):

I hope that you will give a more complete example in the question if this is not adequate.  As it stands I don't see the need to mess with context but given the earlier questions I suspect your example is not representative of what you actually wish to accomplish.

For the given example you could use something like this:

```
x = 2;

Module[{h},
  SetAttributes[h, HoldAllComplete];
  HoldComplete[g["x"]]
    /. y_String :> RuleCondition[h @@ MakeExpression@y]
    /. h[x___] :> x
] // FullForm
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[g[x]]
> ```

This is better than stripping all `Defer` or `HoldComplete` heads as it will not strip heads that were not introduced by the replace operation itself.

Comment: +1. Just for fun: `Delete[HoldComplete[g["x"]] /. y_String :> RuleCondition@MakeExpression@y, {1,1,0}]`

Answer (score 0):

The following function `ReplaceC` evaluates the `Replace` in an alternative context and the strips the context back from the returned value.

```
ReplaceC[data_, rules_] := ToExpression@Replace[
    ToBoxes[
     With[{body =
        ReleaseHold@Replace[HoldComplete@MakeBoxes[
            Replace[x, rules, {0, Infinity}]
            ],
          HoldPattern[x] -> data, {0, Infinity}]
       }, Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}, $Context = "context`"},
       ToExpression@body]
      ]
     ],
    s_String :> StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["^context`"] -> ""],
    {0, Infinity}
    ];
```

Then you can run the following to get `g[x]`.

```
ReplaceC[HoldComplete[g["x"]], {
  y_String :> With[{
     eval = Symbol[y]},
    eval /; True]
  }]
```